# Google Maps api v2 android: How to Remove a single marker?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, marker

In my app i need to have 2 types of markers: the first ones need to stay on a location and the second ones need to move, right now I dont have the static markers yet but my app can show a marker moving if the location of the phone changes but for that i call mMap.clear(), I dont want to clear all markers when the location changes so I need to remove only that marker, I read in another question that I need to use Marker.remove(); to remove individual markers but im not sure where to implement that in the code.

Here is the method for a new location:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mMap.clear();
    GetLatLong();
    handleNewLocation(location);
    mCurrentLocation = location;


}
```

and here is the handleNewLocation method:

```
    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    if (mLastLocation != null) {

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(list.get(0), list.get(1));
        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));


        //añadir un nuevo marker con la posición de la variable latLng
        MarkerOptions camion = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("Camión")
                .snippet("ruta " + ruta)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus));


        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(camion);
        if (marker == null) {
            mMap.addMarker(camion);
        } else {
            camion.position(latLng);

        }

    }
}
```

Thank you.

EDIT:

```
List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    markers.clear();
    GetLatLong();
    handleNewLocation(location);
    mCurrentLocation = location;
}
private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    if (mLastLocation != null) {

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(list.get(0), list.get(1));
        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));


        //añadir un nuevo marker con la posición de la variable latLng
        MarkerOptions camion = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("Camión")
                .snippet("ruta " + ruta)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus));


        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(camion);

        if (marker == null) {

            markers.add(marker);
        } else {
            camion.position(latLng);

        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You said that your app can show a marker moving if the phone location changes, but what determines when you need to remove the marker?

Comment: Try to save the `what-you-want-remove` marker in an `ArrayList` or in a `HashMap`.

Comment: @not_a_bot: when a location changes the handleNewLocation() starts, erase the marker with mMap.clear(); and creates a new one with the new location with handleNewLocation(); I need to change that mMap.clear; to something that doesnt erase allthe markers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to remove one marker - you have to remember this marker first. Then call [marker.remove()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#remove()).

Code:

```
class YourClass {
    Marker singleMarker; //marker to be removed

    public void addMarker() {
        ....
        //here you add your marker
        singleMarker = mMap.addMarker(camion);
    }

    public void removeSingleMarker() {
        if(singleMarker != null) {
            singleMarker.remove();
            singleMarker = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I discussed above, you can try to save the `what-you-want-remove marker` in an `ArrayList` or in a `HashMap`.

Sample code:

```
// before loop:
List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();

// inside your loop:
Marker marker = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(geo1Dub,geo2Dub))); //...
markers.add(marker);

// after loop:
markers.size();
```

Comment: Just check how many markers you have included, you can `comment out` if you do not need it

Comment: It didnt worked man :( Maybe im doing something wrong? I created the ArrayList and tried to implement it but the markers duplicate heres the code ONLOCATIONCHANGED() =  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        markers.clear();
        GetLatLong();
        handleNewLocation(location);
        mCurrentLocation = location;
    }  ADDING NEW MARKER = Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(camion);

            if (marker == null) {

                markers.add(marker);
            } else {
                camion.position(latLng);

            }

Comment: you can edit your question below former, so I can take a look closely